# suexec policy violation: What were these guys up to?

Tags: linux, security, perl, suexec

Have just assumed responsibility for a new client's site.  OS is Linux.  They had a cgi-bin directory below document root.

I was looking at my error.log for an issue with a script and found a number of attempts to access dis-used Perl scripts.  I have removed the entire cgi-bin directory now.

Questions:

Where would I find the suexec log on a Linux VPS?  It is not in /var/log/httpd/suexec_log

How would the attacker have gotten a directory listing of the cgi-bin assuming permissions were correctly set?

Any thoughts on further action now that the cgi-bin has been removed?

```
[Mon Nov 21 01:15:08 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 01:15:08 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: excel.pl
[Mon Nov 21 01:32:30 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 01:32:30 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: forward.pl
[Mon Nov 21 01:49:52 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 01:49:52 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: harvest.pl
[Mon Nov 21 01:58:27 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 01:58:27 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: who.pl
[Mon Nov 21 02:07:14 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 02:07:14 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: thousandwords.pl
[Mon Nov 21 02:17:21 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 02:17:21 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: news.pl
[Mon Nov 21 02:41:58 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 02:41:58 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: environment.pl
[Mon Nov 21 02:52:14 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 02:52:14 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: xpdf.pl
[Mon Nov 21 02:59:20 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 02:59:20 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: mail.pl
[Mon Nov 21 02:59:47 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 02:59:47 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: score.pl
[Mon Nov 21 03:16:42 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 03:16:42 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: pdfextract.pl
[Mon Nov 21 03:16:54 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 03:16:54 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: surveysays.pl
[Mon Nov 21 03:26:22 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 03:26:22 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: surveycookie.pl
[Mon Nov 21 03:51:26 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 03:51:26 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: search.cgi
[Mon Nov 21 04:08:48 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 04:08:48 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: shuffler.pl
[Mon Nov 21 06:37:34 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 21 06:37:34 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: tickerBN.pl
[Mon Nov 21 06:56:58 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec failure: could not open log file
[Mon Nov 21 06:56:58 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] fopen: Permission denied
[Mon Nov 21 06:56:58 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script headers: weatherFind.pl
[Mon Nov 21 08:14:37 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] suexec failure: could not open log file
[Mon Nov 21 08:14:37 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] fopen: Permission denied
[Mon Nov 21 08:14:37 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.193] Premature end of script hea
```

Comment: Got any solutions then please update. I am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

What flavor of Linux? Try /var/log/apache2/suexec.log, but looks like suexec (Apache) does not have permissions to write to the log file. Appears to be a bot looking for vulnerable scripts.